# Common category Page Of custom post type

Tags: wordpress

I have created a custom post type named 'services' and added categories like 'data', 'design' and 'digital'. so want to create common template for all categories within 'services' post type. Please help me how can I create a common template. Thanks in advance.

Screenshot :- https://prnt.sc/1imuek1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that, you need to create a single post file. like `single-services.php` here services is your post type name.

In that file need to add the header and footer and your custom code. check below code format

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

// your code here for the display custom post type

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Since you are using a custom taxonomy and not the native post categories you need to name your file `taxonomy-{taxonomy}.php` and in your case, it would be `taxonomy-mycategories.php`

Take a look at the section of the template hierarchy to display custom taxonomy archives.

Comment: Thanks for you response have created a file named 'taxonomy-services.php' but still its showing below error :- https://prnt.sc/1inp1tv

Comment: just try with /services remove the data

Comment: If all good then can you please upvote the answer as well so others can easily know the answer